# Что отражает счётчик ResSet из NMon (Linux)?

Tags: linux, memory, производительность

Здравствуйте.

В показаниях инструмента мониторинга `NMon` есть счётчик `ResSet`.

В найденной статье прочёл: `Resident Set Size = how big it is in memory (excluding the pages still in the file system (like code) and some parts on paging disks)`.

На сервере запущена `java` (веб-сервер) в 15 процессов. При этом:

- для группы процессов java значение `ResSet` порядка 32 ГБайт (32 000 000 КБайт - суммарно на все процессы `java`) в пике;
- оперативной памяти всего 6 ГБайт;
- подкачка порядка 12 ГБайт.

Если знакомы с устройством памяти в `Linux`, растолкуйте:

1. Из чего складывается `ResSet` на примере работы `java`?
2. Чем является `ResSet` в терминах колонок утилиты `htop` (код - заголовок - пример значения):

   - M_SIZE     - VIRT - 2092 М;
   - M_RESIDENT - RES - 410 М;
   - M_SHARE    - SHR - 12164;
   - M_TRS      - CODE - 4;
   - M_DRS      - DATA - 1975 M
3. Сумма `ResSet` для группы процессов может быть больше, чем сумма `swap + ram` сервера? Почему?

Нашел вопросы по теме:

- [Relationship of Res Set, Res Text and Res Data](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014609646#77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014615443).
- [AIX Memory Usage - or - Who is using the memory and how?](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/aixpert/entry/aix_memory_usage_or_who_is_using_the_memory_and_how20?lang=en)

Прочёл беседы, некоторые вопросы остались.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ответ в [исходных кодах nmon](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nmon/files/lmon15g.c/download):

```
unsigned long statm_resident;   /* resident set size */

...

unsigned long  pagesize = 1024*4; /* Default page size is 4 KB but newer servers compiled with 64 KB pages */

....    

p->procs[i].statm_resident*pagesize/1024UL, /* in KB */
```

ResSet =

- statm_resident * pagesize / 1024 =
- (resident set size) * pagesize / 1024 =
- (resident set size) * (4 * 1024) / 1024 =
- (resident set size) * 4